# png imagesize is 2kb, but getDrawable(id) increase 100kb memory. why?

Tags: android, memory

I use 2kb png file. But when I use getDrawable(id), It increase 110kb memory.. Why ??

==========================================================================

```
printMemory();
Drawable defaultDrawable = resources.getDrawable(resourceID);
printMemory();
```

==========================================================================

```
05-09 11:11:13.849 14268-14268/* I/memory: -----
05-09 11:11:13.849 14268-14268/*: alloc memory : ***30801420***  maxMemory : 44037764
05-09 11:11:13.849 14268-14268/*: alloc memory : ***30906024***  maxMemory : 44037764
05-09 11:11:13.849 14268-14268/* I/memory: -----
```

==========================================================================

Is there better way for this issue?

Comment: a PNG is compressed. To draw it, it needs to be uncompressed. That's probably 4 byte per pixel.

Answer (score 0):

The png file is compressed: if you want to display it all of the pixels need to be uncompressed.